# How to get only projects associated with user with Web Service API

Tags: sonarqube

I'm using SonarQube (ver4.3.2) and I'm trying to get project list that the API caller user is allowed to see. I found a following API which can get project list:

```
http://nemo.sonarsource.org/api/resources
```

When I call this API, then I get all SonarQube's projects though the API caller user doesn't have brows permission for some projects. The API caller a user means user which is authorized by http basic authentication. I want to get only project list which the API caller user can see.

Is it possible?

Regards,

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling the "/api/resources" WS, you will get only the projects you are allowed to see - which indeed means projects for which the user has the "Browse" permission.

If you get all the projects of your SonarQube instance when calling this WS, this means that your permissions allow this and you should review them. For instance, maybe the group "anyone" is set on the "Browse" permission of each project? (which is the default configuration of SonarQube by the way).

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I've confirmed you indication, and I realized that "/api/resources" WS only returns project list wich the API caller user can brows when the client's cookie doesn't contain a login cookie(i.e JSESSIONID). Additionally WS API returns Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID in response header. When API client has an authenticated JSESSIONID in cookie, SonarQube's WS takes this cookie for user authentication though API client has Authorization header in request. Hence Once call WS with Authorization header, rest of WS call is authenticated by cookie. My understanding is right?